# Is there any way to pass the result variable without displaying the <br> tags in the text area?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass the result variable to the text area without displaying the 
 tags?

This is my code.

```
var overtimeRate = 1.5;
var regularHours = prompt("How many regular hours?");  
var overtime = prompt("How many overtime hours?");


var hourRate = prompt("What is the hour rate of pay?");
var overtimeRatePerHour = hourRate * overtimeRate;
var pay = regularHours * hourRate;
var overtimePay = overtime * overtimeRatePerHour;

function calculator() {
  var result = pay + "<br />" + overtimePay + "<br />" + overtimePay + pay;
  document.getElementById("textarea").value = result;
}
```

Comment: Tried \n instead of <br>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently setting the value which is probably marking the tags up. Try setting innerHTML instead, as so:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: maybe try to add something like a p tag around the result